# How do I open files over FTP with Emacs 22.2.1 on Windows?

Tags: windows, emacs, ftp

[AngeFtp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp)?  EFS?
Is there a better option?
Is the preferred option built-in?
If so, how do I turn it on?
If not, where do I download it?

I tried with AngeFtp, just by doing find-file using a filespec like

```
/name@server:/directory
```

and it prompts me for a password, then does the login to the FTP server and gets the contents - it takes a while - but when it finishes, I don't get or see a dired buffer. I just get a blank buffer with a weird name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) is the modern replacement for ange-ftp.

The short version is, you specify a file like "/myusername@host:path/to/file". Works like a charm.

View the linked documentation for installation instructions, though it might already be installed if you have a fairly new installation of emacs. Also, [there are several questions related to tramp and remote development with emacs on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=emacs+tramp)

Comment: Tramp seems to do 217 different things, which is great.  I just want to do dired and find-file over ftp.  Readin the tramp page, it says that it forwards all FTP requests to Ange-FTP.  So... it doesn't really replace it, it's just another layer?  Do I want this other layer if the first layer didn't work for me?

Comment: You are correct. AFAIK, Tramp adds nothing to the mix for FTP -- it just passes the file/dir along to ange-ftp.

Answer (score 1):

I just use `C-x C-f` or `C-x C-d`, with the remote-file format `/host:/path/to/my/dir/`.  And I customize `tramp-default-method` to "ftp".  Works like a charm.  When it opens the connection for the first time (only), it prompts for the password.